# Best Way to Get Specific Row From Stored Procedure Query

Tags: vb.net, string, stored-procedures, csv

I have a web app I am building that has primarily multiple choice questions with a few short answers. As is all the answers are put into the database via stored procedure, and then are extracted and corrected using a different procedure. While the short answer questions are included in the queries they are not being printed to the page, instead i have them also stored in a session variable and and printed in their respective textboxes, the problem is the reviewer can no longer see them if the session is timed out. So I am wondering how in VB.net do you extract a specific row from a query and then work with it from there.

this is what i have currently

```
    Dim P2Ans As String
    P2Ans = Session("Part2")
    Dim Part2Txt As New ArrayList(P2Ans.Split("|"c))
    Normal.Text = Part2Txt(0)
    Normal2.Text = Part2Txt(1)
    Normal3.Text = Part2Txt(2)
```

what i want is something like this

```
    Dim P2Ans As String
    P2Ans = Select.Tables(Answers).Where("QuestionID =X") 'from there take the answer out of the column "Question Answer"

    Dim Part2Txt As New ArrayList(P2Ans.Split("|"c))
    Normal.Text = Part2Txt(0)
    Normal2.Text = Part2Txt(1)
    Normal3.Text = Part2Txt(2)
```

i dont know if this is possible or best practice, so any advice would be great.

my answer: something like this

```
        Dim queryString As String = "SELECT questionAnswer FROM Submissions where   submissionid =" + SID + "and questionNumber = 1"
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnString)
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
            connection.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an SqlCommand object, pass it the query (i.e. SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE questionid = 'x') and then use SqlDataReader to retrieve the answer and save it to a variable and / or control on your form.

Comment: i thought of this but I figured since the data was already available to me, i'd try and use it, for consistancy sake

Comment: Why not just extend the session time out and keep doing what you are doing then?

Comment: because people may be looking at these weeks/ months down the road